# How to get more points on a mesh (edit mode)?

Tags: customization

I am trying to stretch the sides of an circle to get a very specific shape. I know about the control+r methode but I just don't feel like to spam that over and over again, there must be another way.

Comment: Scrolling your mouse wheel after pressing Ctrl+R but before hitting enter increases/decreases the number of loopcuts.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley is there a way to do it with the whole circle at once?

Comment: Could you post an image of the circle in Edit mode? May make it easier to understand how the vertices or loopcuts need to be added.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley it is the deafult one in the currently newest version

Comment: Probably, you want to subdivide all (or selected) parts of the circle: select them, then hit W and choose 'subdivide' (the amount of subdivisions can be changed in the toolshelf)

Comment: I would do a grid fill. When adding the circle, set _Fill Type_ to _Nothing_ (this is the default). Then in Edit mode, hit Ctrl+F followed by G.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley the subdivide thing worked you can post that as an answer mate!

Comment: It was @lemon who said it. But I posted an answer with an explanation of how to get more vertices at creation, and I also mentioned subdividing to get more vertices on an already created object. Whether you use hit W then select Subdivide, as suggested by lemon, or click the Subdivide button in the toolshelf, as in my answer, is irrelevant. Those are two different ways of accessing the exact same tool. Use whichever you find more convenient.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments I made, I probably misinterpreted the question. I never actually considered that you may be trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on just the rim of the circle, and I thought you were trying to get more points on the surface of a filled circle.

The easiest way the get more vertices on the rim of a circle, is specifying the number of vertices when you add it. This is done in the *Toolshelf* right after adding the circle. If you do not see the toolshelf, make it visible by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

To add more vertices to an already created circle (or any object), you can subdivide it. In Edit mode there's a *Subdivide* button in the Toolshelf.

[image]

You may want to increase the *Smoothness* parameter. It's set to 0.000 by default, and this will make straight cuts. Setting it to 1.000 will make smoother cuts.

[image]